# Jasper dynamic number of rows in table

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a table in jasper which can have dynamic number of raws and I don't know how many would be. And after table I have a textField. Is it possible to make margin of textfield from the BOTTOM of the table?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You have to set the position of the text field as Float.

1. Select the text field component in the Outline view
2. Now, in the Properties view, select Appearance tab
3. Under location, chose Position type value as Float from the dropdown